# How to avoid a bash script from failing when -e option is set?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have a bash script with `-e` option set, which fails the whole script on the very first error.

In the script, I am trying to do an `ls` on a directory. But that path may or may not exist. If the path does not exist, the `ls` command fails, since the `-e` flag is set.

Is there a way by which I can prevent the script from failing?

As a side note, I have tried the trick to do an `set +e` and `set -e` before and after that command and it works. But I am looking for some better solution.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can "catch" the error using `||` and a command guaranteed to exit with 0 status:

```
ls $PATH || echo "$PATH does not exist"
```

Since the compound command succeeds whether or not `$PATH` exists, `set -e` is not triggered and your script will not exit.

To suppress the error silently, you can use the `true` command:

```
ls $PATH || true
```

To execute multiple commands, you can use one of the compound commands:

```
ls $PATH || { command1; command2; }
```

or

```
ls $PATH || ( command1; command2 )
```

Just be sure nothing fails inside either compound command, either. One benefit of the second example is that you can turn off immediate-exit mode inside the subshell without affecting its status in the current shell:

```
ls $PATH || ( set +e; do-something-that-might-fail )
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I still have couple of doubts. If the `ls` command fails, it still prints a message, that so and so path doe snot exist, is there a way to suppress that? Also, in the `OR` part, is there a way to execute 2 lines of code?

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to use `trap` to catch the `EXIT` signal:

```
trap 'echo "ls failed" ; some_rescue_action' EXIT
ls /non_exist
```

Answer (score 3):

one solution would be testing the existence of the folder

```
function myLs() {
    LIST=""
    folder=$1
    [ "x$folder" = "x" ] && folder="."
    [ -d $folder ] && LIST=`ls $folder`
    echo $LIST
}
```

This way bash won't fail if `$folder` does not exist